# Build Failure in Jenkins in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ant, jenkins, ubuntu-12.04

I have setup jenkins on my system.I am trying to invoke build.xml in the ant section for which i have specified the path `/home/blank/Downloads/build.xml` in the build section of invoke ant but when I try to build my job it executes with the following error

> BUILD FAILED
>
> /home/blank/Downloads/build.xml:48: Unable to delete directory /home/blank/Downloads/bin

there is some problems with the permission how do i set this such that the folder bin gets deleted.

I am new to Ubuntu and finding it difficult to work with permission.Need help

Comment: As what user is Jenkins running? The jenkins user needs permission to delete that directory.

Comment: how to determine which user has jenkins running

Comment: run `ps -eo euser,args | grep jenkins` on the machine. The first column is the user that is executing the process

Comment: I tried it but it gives me              Command 'ps' is available in '/bin/ps'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: is this a clean Ubuntu install? Do you have root privileges?

Comment: Yes I have root privilages

Answer (score 0):

Open **/etc/sysconfig/jenkins** or **/etc/default** ( you should have one of those 2 files on your PC, I think the first one is for Ubuntu) and search for JENKINS_USER. And you'll find which user is running Jenkins as.

In that file you can change the user to one that have permissions but you'll also have to change the ownership of :

/var/lib/jenkins

/var/cache/jenkins

/var/log/jenkins

and restart Jenkins.

Comment: I am having problem with restarting jenkins it gives me  * Restarting Jenkins Continuous Integration Server jenkins         java: no process found
daemon: no process found\

Comment: and when i try to get the status of jenkins it shows me 14 instances of jenkins are running at the moment
but the pidfile /var/run/jenkins/jenkins.pid is missing